# How to use email instead of username in cakephp and cakedc user plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakedc

I am using cakedc plugin. It is using username and password for the user login, I want to login with email instead of username. I do not want want the username to be there or stored in the database. Can anybody please help me how can i do it?

P.S. Plugin installed using composer in vendor directory

Comment: I think you have to extend it. You can use similar plugin https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-user-tools which uses email for login.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Auth.authenticate.Form.fields configuration to let AuthComponent use the email instead of the username for user identify. Add this line to your bootstrap.php file, after CakeDC/Users Plugin is loaded

```
Configure::write('Auth.authenticate.Form.fields.username', 'email');
```

Override the login.ctp template to change the Form->control to "email". Add (or copy from the https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/src/Template/Users/login.ctp) the file login.ctp to path /src/Template/Plugin/CakeDC/Users/Users/login.ctp and ensure it has the following content

```
    // ... inside the Form
    <?= $this->Form->control('email', ['required' => true]) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->control('password', ['required' => true]) ?>
    // ... rest of your login.ctp code
```

We've added specific instructions here https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Configuration.md#using-the-users-email-to-login